How many records should I put in a DynamoDb partition?
How many records should I aim to put into a DynamoDb partition?
I'm designing a table which will store about a thousand records per user where the PK is the user's id. The average record size is about 500 bytes. How can I know if I have 'too many' records?

Just because the first answer didn't address it, are you asking about DynamoDb throttling due to bad partition keys?  Some discussion [here]

Thanks for that, it's a very relevant point and a useful link. It's not the focus of my concern here however, I'm happy with the read/write frequency per partition, I was curious to understand if there was any reason for me to be concerned about the amount of data per partition. It appears not.

This looks like a very useful reference with regard to throttling and 'hot' partitions

You can never have too many records, feel free to store as many as you like.
One caveat to that is if you use a Local Secondary Index (LSI), in which case data related to a user would not be able to exceed 10GB. 99.99% of people don't require a LSI so you should have no issue also.

Is there any performance impact as the partition grows? If I put 10 records in a partition and accessed them with a query, then added a whole lot of data into the same partition and issued the same 10 record query would there be any impact on the query response time?

None, your condition on the sort key would target the same 10 items, and that's precisely how DynamoDB maintains predictable performance at scale. 1GB of data has the same performance as 1PB of data.

Thanks Leeroy. Good to know. I'll (continue to) concern myself with the frequency of access to data and the partition/sort keys to best support it and I'll stop thinking about the number of rows that will actually be stored :-)
